# Why is my CROSS APPLY column not showing up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I think I might be asking the wrong question, but here it goes. I have a fairly complex query and I know I need to do some CROSS APPLYs to make it work, but when I created my initial query that worked fine and then added a CROSS APPLY at the end, the specified column in my CROSS APPLY don't show up when I execute my query. It's weird. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the syntax but I don't know what it is.

Here is a simplified version of my query:

```
/* I have some ctes */
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id > 50)

/* Normal query */
SELECT b1, b2, b3 
FROM B
INNER JOIN cte ON b.b1 = cte.b1
INNER JOIN X on b.x1 = X.x1

/* Cross Apply, this is my real code */
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 (Family.GroupID) AS "Family"
    FROM (
        SELECT HIFIS_Clients.ClientID,
            HIFIS_Groups.GroupID,
            HIFIS_People_Groups.GroupHeadYN,
            HIFIS_People_Groups.DateStart,
            ISNULL(HIFIS_People_Groups.DateEnd,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS "DateEnd"

        FROM HIFIS_Clients
            INNER JOIN HIFIS_People ON HIFIS_Clients.PersonID = HIFIS_People.PersonID
            INNER JOIN HIFIS_People_Groups ON HIFIS_People.PersonID = HIFIS_People_Groups.PersonID
            INNER JOIN HIFIS_Groups ON HIFIS_People_Groups.GroupID = HIFIS_Groups.GroupID

        WHERE HIFIS_Groups.GroupTypeID = 1

        ) Family
    WHERE Family.ClientID = B.ClientID
    ORDER BY Family.GroupID
) Family
```

Am I not allowed to use JOINS in the same query as a CROSS APPLY? Is there something wrong with using ctes? My query runs fine without the CROSS APPLY. The SELECT statement in the CROSS APPLY runs fine on its own. I'm not getting a syntax error...

My output in this hypothetical example would be

| b1 | b2 | b3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2 | 40 |

So there's no column for "Family." Why is it missing?

Comment: You actually need to include it in your `SELECT` clause...  `SELECT b1, b2, b3, Family.Family` *(You should also fully qualify **which** table the columns `b1, b2, b3` come from.)*

Comment: Oh hey, is it that easy? Thanks! I will give that a try. (And yes, I am fully qualifying my other columns but this was a majorly simplified example)

Comment: I think because you don't output data from cross apply in the main query . I mean it should be SELECT b1, b2, b3 ,Family.Family